# Installation stuck on logo

Tags: system-installation

I've been trying to install elementary on an old computer but it seems to be stuck on the logo. I'm booting the installation from a USB. The hard drive was previously formatted, so no existing operating systems.

Its been on the logo for an hour and a half

I'm new to Linux, sorry if I didn't provide enough info.

Comment: You can switch off the logo by pressing "F1" or "Esc". Please edit your question and provide some messages from the screen.